# Where to declare collections when files are split between server and client directories?

Tags: meteor

I am struggling with Meteor when using separate client and server directories and was hoping someone could help me.

My server code in the server subdirectory looks like:

```
Testing = new Meteor.Collection("testing");

Testing.insert({hello1:'world1'});
Testing.insert({hello2:'world2'});
Testing.insert({hello3:'world3'});

Meteor.publish("testing", function() {
console.log('server: ' + Testing.find().count());
return Testing.find();
});
```

My client code in the client subdirectory looks like:

```
Meteor.subscribe("testing");
var Testing = new Meteor.Collection("testing");
console.log('count: ' + Testing.find().count());
```

I have tried this with autopublish on and off.

In my terminal window, I can see the log statement output a number of items as I would expect. But for my client, in the browser console window I always see a count of 0.

Not sure if this is related, but when I modify my subscribe statement and save my changes, I see this error in my console window:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/sockjs/574/ukpxre9v/xhr 503 (Service Unavailable) sockjs-    0.3.4.js:821
AbstractXHRObject._start sockjs-0.3.4.js:821
(anonymous function)
```

I'm sure I'm making some stupid mistake, but I haven't had any luck tracking it down. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running `console.log('count: ' + Testing.find().count());` too soon Meteor will sync your server collection down to the client but it takes a very short amount of time.

For instance you could run `console.log('count: ' + Testing.find().count());` in your web console it should give you a proper result because you would have waited half a second or so for it to load the data down from the server.

You could put this code in a [reactive context](http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity) so it shows the live count correctly, such as [Meteor.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_autorun) or a [Template helper](http://docs.meteor.com/#templates).

The reason you see that 503 XHR error is when you modify your code and save it, meteor restarts and serves up the new content asap, so the socket between the client and server is temporarily interrupted, until it refreshes the page. This is not really anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Ah that makes sense - it works perfectly now; that is quite a nice setup. Thanks for your help!